# Error with ExecuteMany function from psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to extract data from excel and then insert data into postgres database using psycopg2 in python.
I am using executemany to insert in database and passing insert sql statement and its values as parameters to it. It  is throwing error 'string index out of range'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import psycopg2 as psycopg2
import csv


'''
sample values is: 
('123924902','ABC_DEF_GHI_NG',current_user,now() at time zone 'utc',current_user,now() at time zone 'utc')
'''

def extract_from_file(excel_file, sheet_index, row_for_header, output_file):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name=sheet_index, header=None)
    new_header = df.iloc[row_for_header]
    ##print(new_header)
    df = df[row_for_header+1:]
    df.columns=new_header
    rows_to_insert = []
    
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        ##print(row['Sector'])
        if pd.isnull(row['ENTITY_ID']):
            continue##or break if we 
            ##are confident no intervening empty rows
        if  not pd.isnull(row['ENTITY_ID']):
            row_to_insert = ["('"+str(row['ENTITY_ID'])+"'",
            "'"+str(row['SECT_CD'])+"'),"]
            
            row_to_insert = ','.join(row_to_insert)
            rows_to_insert.append(row_to_insert)

    rows_to_insert[-1] = rows_to_insert[-1][:-1]    
    with open(output_file,'w') as out:
        for row in rows_to_insert:
            out.write(row+'\n')


extract_from_file('EntityTableImportTest.xlsx', 0,0, 'EntityTableImportTest.txt')

def insert_entity_list():
    """ insert multiple entities into the entity table  """
    sql = "INSERT into esg.entity(entity_id,sector_key,creat_by,creat_dtm,last_upd_by,last_upd_dtm) VALUES(%s,(select sector_key from esg.sector where sector_cd=%s),current_user,now() at time zone 'utc',current_user,now() at time zone 'utc')"
    conn = None
    with open('EntityTableImportTest.txt','r') as out:
        entity_list = out.read()
        print(entity_list)
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="abc",user="abcde",password="abcdefg")
        # create a new cursor
        print(conn)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        
        cur.executemany(sql,entity_list)
        # commit the changes to the database
        conn.commit()
        # close communication with the database
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()


insert_entity_list()
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What is `print(entity_list)` returning?

Comment: ('123924902','ABC_DEF_GHI_NG'),
('121109671','ABC_UNR_UTL_PWR')                                                                                       I corrected extract_from_file function to output set of values in text file with comma between them.

Comment: A) That does not look like a list of tuples which needs to be passed to `executemany`. B) Even if you enclose that in a list there are two values in each tuple and only one placeholder(`%s`) in the query string, so that is not going to work.

Comment: There are two placeholders in query string.                                                                                  "INSERT into esg.entity(entity_id,sector_key,creat_by,creat_dtm,last_upd_by,last_upd_dtm) VALUES(%s,(select sector_key from esg.sector where sector_cd=%s),current_user,now() at time zone 'utc',current_user,now() at time zone 'utc')"

Comment: Also changed to cur.executemany(sql,[  dict(value=v) for v in entity_list ]) and changed placeholder to %(value)s. This got rid of error I was facing previously but still not able to insert into table in postgres.                                                                                                                       Thank you for replying on this question.

Comment: Oops, missed the second one. In any case you need a list of tuples(or dicts) to pass to `executemany`. FYI, I would turn those `current_user, now()` etc into defaults on the columns. Also if the datetime fields are `timestamptz` you can get rid of `at time zone 'UTC'`.

Comment: You still haven't proved to me `entity_list` is actually a list. What does `type(entity_list)` return?

Comment: So did you get a new error? Or how did you determine it was not inserted?

Comment: @Kavya: Please provide the full traceback (including line numbers, ...). Did you try your code for just one recordset ? Are there empty lines in your text file ?

Comment: I can't add defaults to columns in database due to their requirements.                                           audit fields are timestamp with timezone datatype fields.                                                               figured out that read() is outputting file content as string.So when I changed it to out.read().splitlines(), entitylist was coming as list of lists.                                                         There is no error now but it is not inserting data yet.

Comment: output is : ["('123924902','ABC_DEF_GHI_NG')", "('121109671','ABC_UNR_UTL_PWR')"]
<class 'list'>

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I tried for one recordset no change in output and there are no empty lines.                                                                                                              output for one record in excel : ["('123924902','ABC_DEF_GHI_NG')"]
<class 'list'>

Comment: The excel file is not relevant, it's the txt file you are generating. `entity_list` is the whole file content as a string, because that is what `.read()` returns. I assume you want to read the text file line-by-line and convert it into a Python data structure.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver when I queried data in entity table for these entity_id in file, I couldn't see any record. So it is not inserted.

Comment: ... as you already iterating over the Excel data, I might be more efficient to do the insert there.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer When I used read().splitlines(), it is coming as list of lists. and when I did print(type(entity_list)) it gave output <class 'list'>.                                                             Can you elaborate on efficient way to do insert you mentioned? is combining above two functions into one or any other way?

Comment: Please delete the question and rewrite it from scratch as we are ending to much comments. Provide all information/sample data from the files, needed to help you tp find an adequate solution.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I created new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900657/error-while-inserting-data-from-excel-into-postgres-db-using-psycopg2                                                                               Please check the above link and let me know if you need anything regarding the issue.